# Wordpress query specific post

Tags: wordpress, attachment

I've created a "portafolio" custom type in Wordpress and I would like to query a specific post (ID = 780 to be exact) in this code I've written, which retrieves all attachments images inside that post:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


    <?php if ( $post->post_type == 'portafolio' && $post->post_status == 'publish' ) {
            $attachments = get_posts( array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id(),
                'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
                'order'           => 'ASC'  

    ) );?>

    <?php
            if ( $attachments ) {
                foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                    $class = "post-attachment mime-" . sanitize_title( $attachment->post_mime_type );
                    $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'original', false ); ?>


    {image : '<?php echo '' . $thumbimg[0] . ''; ?>', title : '<?php wp_title("",true); ?>', thumb : ''},

    <?php               
                }

            }
        }
    ?>


<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

However, I don't know where in that code I should query the specific post I want to retrieve.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have tried:

```
<?php
    query_posts( array('p' => 780) );
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    ?>

    <h2>Test</h2>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Just to see if I was able to retrieve something, without luck.

If this helps, I am doing this so I can create a page on Wordpress to display a single post of a custom type called "portafolio" and then assign it as frontpage.

Comment: You don't have to create a fake page for this, you can simply modify your home template, take a look here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your query by calling `query_posts` before [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop):

```
query_posts( array('p' => $myPostID) );
```

Simply call this function before your loop. Your final code could be like this:

```
<?php
query_posts( array('p' => 780) );
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
```

You can specify even more [parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters), like authors, or post-types, etc. Call `rewind_posts()` after `endwhile; endif;`, if you have another loop after your main loop.

**EDIT:**

A few comments later... be sure to add 'post_type' to your function, if you're working with custom post types. For example:

```
query_posts( array('p' => 780, 'post_type' => 'book') );
```

Comment: Hi martinCzerwi, thanks for your answer. I have tried the following code just to test if I was able to retrieve the query without success. I've edited the question for you to see the code.

Comment: Just to be sure, according to your edit-code, you see `<h2>Test</h2>` 0 times, meaning it doesn't loop? I've copied exactly your edit-code but changed the ID, and it works just fine (shows Test 1 time). You can even create a template-file like `home.php` with only including your code, to make it work.

Comment: That is correct martinCzerwi. I have created a home.php file with the provided code and it's not looping. I don't see the "test" heading. Don't know if this might help to clarify, but the post I am trying to retrieve is from a custom type.

Comment: Good hint, I added a custom post type, it didn't work until I had this: `query_posts( array('p' => 780, 'post_type' => 'portafolio') );`

Comment: Hi martinCzerwi, thanks a lot! That was definitely what was missing :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) :

```
$my_id = 780;
$my_post = get_post($my_id);
```

Comment: Hi Soju, thanks for your answer. Where in my code should I put these variables? I'm not sure which ones to replace.

Comment: It depends, why do you want to query this post ? Where do you want to display it ?

Comment: It's a page I am creating to display a single post and then display it  in the homepage. From what I understand, Wordpress won't allow single posts to be selected as front pages.